# Create list of specific columns from statistical test

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am looking into stationarity of my data. I run the adfuller test for each of my variable and in the next steap I want to create a column list or rather a dataframe for the stationary and non-stationary data, so that I can change the list with pct.change.

It looks like this atm:

```
print("Observations of Dickey-fuller test \n")
print("stationary columns \n")

adf_results = {}

for col in df.columns.values:
    dftest = adfuller(df[col],autolag='AIC')
    if dftest[1] < 0.05:
        col_list.append(df[[col]])
        print(col + " is stationary")
```

This works exactly how I want it.
However, if I try to get the output of the columns with:

```
list(col_list)
```

I receive the list as I want it, but also the column name including all the data points. See example below

```
[col1,
col2,
Time
 01.02.2008     35241.98000
 01.03.2008     42194.62000
 01.04.2008     51419.81818
Name: col1, dtype: float64,
Time
 01.02.2008     0
 01.03.2008     3
 01.04.2008     2
Name: col2, dtype: float64,
```

I just want the upper part:

```
[col1,
col2
]
```

So that afterwards I can create two new dataframes.
My approach is to get the list and then create the df with that information:

```
dfstationary= df[list(col_list)]
```

I feel like this is something very basic, so I am looking for the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that result because you are also appending the content of the column(`df[[col]]`) to `col_list` instead of just the column name (`col`).
To get just the column names, you can use:

```
print("Observations of Dickey-fuller test \n")
print("stationary columns \n")

adf_results = {}
col_list = []
for col in df.columns.values:
    dftest = adfuller(df[col],autolag='AIC')
    if dftest[1] < 0.05:
        col_list.append(col)
        print(col + " is stationary")
#view list of stationary columns
print(col_list)
```